# A more efficient way to interrogate data inside a Dataset: a generic relational map

Tags: data, dataset, associations, data-structures, query

I have a Dataset that stores the relationships between people IDs (in columns) and the events they attended (in rows). I want to produce a linear text report of those relationships.
How can I do this in a way that is good/best practice optimised for Mathematica?

Dataset dsMeetings2  is of the form ' a table with named columns' 
The number '1' signifies that a person (represented by a column - 4 onwards) attended an event

This dataset can be arbitrarily large : 
  so, variable columns, variable rows.

```
dsMeetings2 = Dataset@{{<|"id" -> 1, "date" -> "1/03/20", "name" -> "subject-1", 
    "100" -> 1, "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, 
    "104" -> 0, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 0, 
    "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 2, "date" -> "8/03/20", 
    "name" -> "subject-2", "100" -> 1, "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, 
    "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, 
    "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 3, "date" -> "15/03/20", 
    "name" -> "subject-3", "100" -> 1, "106" -> 1, "101" -> 0, 
    "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, 
    "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 4, "date" -> "22/03/20", 
    "name" -> "subject-4", "100" -> 1, "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, 
    "105" -> 0, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, "108" -> 1, "103" -> 1, 
    "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 5, "date" -> "29/03/20", 
    "name" -> "subject-5", "100" -> 1, "106" -> 0, "101" -> 1, 
    "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, 
    "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 6, "date" -> "5/04/20", 
    "name" -> "subject-6", "100" -> 1, "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, 
    "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, 
    "109" -> 1, "111" -> 1|>}}
```

First, I identify the headers:

```
PersonIDs = 
 Keys[dsMeetings2[1, Range[4, Dimensions[dsMeetings2][[2]]]] ]
```

Next, I declare a function fnT to report the relationship

```
fnT[a_, b_] := Module [{ret = Null},
  ret = ToString[
    "id:\"" <> a <> "\" is-related-to PersonID:\"" <> b <> "\""]; ret
  ]
```

Then, I iterate through the table with those keys

```
result = (If [#[[2]] == 1, fnT[ToString[#[[1]]], Keys[#][[2]]], 
         ""]) &  /@ dsMeetings2[ # &, {"id", #}] & /@ PersonIDs // 
   Normal // TableForm
```

Which results in a report like this:

```
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
(* ... *)
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
(*............etcetera...............*)
```

One issue with this approach is that it reports a "blank" line where there is no relationship, which is inefficient.

Could a better Functional Programming (FP) approach be used so it reports only when there is a relationship?

Also, I would value suggestions on how this can be made more readable/maintainable.. I am new to FP, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way of getting the relationships by constructing a graph. Here is a modification of your approach.

```
dsMeetings2 = 
 Dataset@{<|"id" -> 1, "date" -> "1/03/20", "name" -> "subject-1", 
    "100" -> 1, "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, 
    "104" -> 0, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|
    "id" -> 2, "date" -> "8/03/20", "name" -> "subject-2", "100" -> 1,
     "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 3, 
    "date" -> "15/03/20", "name" -> "subject-3", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 1, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 4, 
    "date" -> "22/03/20", "name" -> "subject-4", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 0, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 1, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 5, 
    "date" -> "29/03/20", "name" -> "subject-5", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 6, 
    "date" -> "5/04/20", "name" -> "subject-6", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 1|>}

personIDs = dsMeetings2[1, 4 ;;] // Keys // Normal

fnT[a_, b_] := ToString["id:\"" <> a <> "\" is-related-to PersonID:\"" <> b <> "\""]

(If[#[[2]] == 1, fnT[ToString[#[[1]]], Keys[#][[2]]], Nothing]) & /@ 
      dsMeetings2[# &, {"id", #}] & /@ personIDs // Normal // Flatten //Sort // Column

(*
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"101"
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"102"
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"1" is-related-to PersonID:"106"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"101"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"103"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"2" is-related-to PersonID:"106"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"102"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"104"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"3" is-related-to PersonID:"106"
id:"4" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"4" is-related-to PersonID:"103"
id:"4" is-related-to PersonID:"108"
id:"4" is-related-to PersonID:"109"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"101"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"102"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"104"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"5" is-related-to PersonID:"109"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"100"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"103"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"105"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"109"
id:"6" is-related-to PersonID:"111"

*)
```

Comment: I see your point @Rohit I haven't worked with graph data structures before but I could give it a try... perhaps, converting the DataSet to a SparseArray and go from there..

Thanks for your suggestions ~ the Dataset subsetting notation helps! and I see that the Module wasn't necessary here..

Comment: ..plus I see how Nothing[] is useful here :-D

I doubt that Flatten[] does anything in this instance, though...
This approach iterates through the entire dataset, so, as you mention a graph approach might be more optimal...