# Internal error using part specification with Dataset

Tags: bugs, dataset

**Bug introduced in 12.1.0. Fixed in 12.1.1**

---

**Update 2020-04-13**

WRI has confirmed that this is a bug. CASE:4530401

Suggested workaround from WRI

```
Dataset[dsMeetings2[All, {1, 3 ;;}], MaxItems -> {Automatic, Automatic, All}]
```

---

While trying to answer [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219246/58370) question I encountered an internal error using a `Part` specification to extract data for specific columns from a dataset.

```
$Version
(* 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020) *)

PacletObject["TypeSystem"]["Version"]
(* 12.1.0.2 *)

dsMeetings2 = 
 Dataset@{<|"id" -> 1, "date" -> "1/03/20", "name" -> "subject-1", 
    "100" -> 1, "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, 
    "104" -> 0, "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|
    "id" -> 2, "date" -> "8/03/20", "name" -> "subject-2", "100" -> 1,
     "106" -> 1, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 3, 
    "date" -> "15/03/20", "name" -> "subject-3", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 1, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 0, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 4, 
    "date" -> "22/03/20", "name" -> "subject-4", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 0, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 1, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 5, 
    "date" -> "29/03/20", "name" -> "subject-5", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 1, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 1, "104" -> 1, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 0, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> 6, 
    "date" -> "5/04/20", "name" -> "subject-6", "100" -> 1, 
    "106" -> 0, "101" -> 0, "105" -> 1, "102" -> 0, "104" -> 0, 
    "108" -> 0, "103" -> 1, "109" -> 1, "111" -> 1|>}

dsMeetings2[All, {1, 3 ;;}]
```

> General::interr2: An unknown internal error occurred. Consult
> Internal`$LastInternalFailure for potential information.

[image]

This unexpectedly works fine

```
dsMeetings2[All, {1, 3 ;;}] // Normal
```

so does this

```
dsMeetings2[All, {1, 4 ;;}]
```

Any ideas for workarounds without converting to `Normal`?

I will report this to WRI.