# "Unknown internal error" in Dataset via Map—bug?

Tags: dataset

If someone else can reproduce this, I'll report it as a bug.

It seems that trying to access a `Dataset` inside another `Dataset` via `Map` returns an inscrutable error:

```
f[Dataset[{1, 2}]] /@ Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]
```

Output:
[image: An image with a message with tag General saying "An unknown internal error occurred. Consult Internal`$LastInternalFailure for potential information." and an output that's a red box enclosing the text "data no longer present" in parentheses.]

Note that this happens with query syntax too: `Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>][All, f[Dataset[{1, 2}]]]` gives the same result.

I'm on version 13.0.0.0.

Comment: Interesting, for both examples, adding `// Normal` does not generate an internal error.

Comment: "f[Dataset[{1, 2}]]" is not a function that you can map on a dataset.

Comment: @DanielHuber Agreed, but it should not result in an internal error. Another example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219293/58370) where `Normal` suppresses the internal error.

Comment: "Normal" will change a dataset to an association. However, I think it is not worth the time to ponder why wrong syntax give this or that error message.

Comment: @DanielHuber `f[Dataset[{1, 2}]]` is perfectly fine (and relatively standard!) syntax if e.g. `f[x_][y_]` is well-defined via subvalues. You can just as well consider `f2[Dataset[{1, 2}], #] &` if you like, though. The same error occurs. My goal here is to give a minimal example, and mapping a generic `f[Dataset[{1, 2}]]`, and thus tacitly suggesting that subvalues are being used, is one not-too-unusual way to do that. It's not wrong syntax.

Comment: Interestingly, though, it seems that if the resulting expression does not explicitly include a `Dataset` one way or another, though, no error occurs! So the problem seems to be having expressions in `Dataset`s which include `Dataset`s...well, in some cases, but not all, weirdly. It seems to demand a "non-dataset wrapper" be in the result: `f[x_][y_] := {x ,y}` produces no error, but `f[x_][y_] := d[x, y]` does. Expressions in `Dataset`s containing `Dataset`s like this sometimes do happen. In any case, even if Mathematica wants you to never do that, returning an error like this is bad design!

Comment: Also, I'm realizing it might just be a problem with the output form. Wrapping things in `FullForm` shows the computation succeeded.